# Java application on Linux

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel

**I'm new to LINUX and java programming.**
I've a Server and Client application. Sever is developed using C# programming runs on a windows machine. Currently I've developed client application in java which runs on Linux machine. But Now I need client side application to start on the boot up of the LINUX OS. **I don't want to use  any LINUX existing OS like Ubuntu or any other and I need to compile my Linux Kernel and run this client side Java application.** *If possible where do I get started ???*

Comment: *I don't want to use any LINUX distributions* but you have to work with Linux ... you're contradicting yourself

Comment: You won't be able to use Java on Linux without a minimal distribution.... And you need to take time to learn Linux. So do yourself a favor: install a friendly distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, ...) on your laptop and start learning Linux. Don't compile a kernel while you are newbie.

Comment: **sorry**, I mean to say I don't want to use any existing OS like ubuntu or any other OS.. I just want to compile my own linux kernel and do this....

Comment: But compiling a Linux kernel requires a Linux system....

Comment: Why do you need to compile your Kernel for running your java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your client code is doing. If it has *very* minimal requirements, then you can bundle a linux kernel (from any distribution), a bootloader, a JRE and your client code. The JRE and client code should go into a file system, perhaps an initial ram fs so you don't have to worry about disk file systems. If you compile the kernel from source, you can even give a directory containing the initramfs content, so you could build this directly into the kernel. You'd then plug the JRE invocation as the  `init=` argument on the kernel command line. Again, if you compile the kernel from source, you can include parts of the command line there.

The above assumes that you require *no* userland tools at all. This is an increasingly inappropriate assumption for most modern systems, since userland tools are used to load drivers, firmware, device configurations, and a million other jobs required to get the system up and running. So you might have to supply a minimal userland. Have a look at [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/about.html) for ways to accomplish this. Many embedded linux devices choose this route.

If your client should be able to present a graphical user interface, then you need an X server as well. You can compile that from source as well, but with all the different drivers involved here, and all the different dependencies, I'd suggest building on an existing distribution here. [`debootstrap`](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) can e.g. be used to create a minimal Debian or Ubuntu installation, which might be used as a starting point for further customizations. This is the route I've chosen for [one of my own projects](https://launchpad.net/liab).

> I don't want to use any LINUX existing OS like Ubuntu or any other and I need to compile my Linux Kernel

I see little chance of creating a customized Linux installation (in one of the shapes described above) without using a full-featured linux environment for the development. If you don't feel at home in a multi-boot setup, you can run your linux build environment in a virtualized environment, e.g. using [qemu](http://qemu.org/) or [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).